# Regex within awk from txt file with one line

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, regular-expression, text-formatting

I am currently working on a script to wipe hard drives. The first script is already working and checks if there are new hard drives available. If there is a new disk available it will list it in a `statuslist.txt` and use `areca_cli disk create drv=X` to set it on `Pass Through`.

Within `statuslist.txt`all new disks are stored by  slot number and model type. Unfortunately, all entries are listed in one line rather than each entry per line. I think this is complicating things for further work with the `statuslist.txt`.

Entries:
`Slot#1 ST3500413AS Slot#2 SEAGATE ST32000444SS Slot#3 INTEL SSDSC2BA100G3 Slot#6 ST320LT007-9ZV142 Slot#8 SEAGATE ST32000444SS`

For the `statuslist.txt` I use the following command.

```
slist=$(areca_cli disk info | awk -F "   *" '{if ($5 != "N.A." && $7 == "Free") print($4" "$5); }')
echo $slist >> /home/user/statuslist.txt
```

This is the second script to wipe hard drives listed in `statuslist.txt`.

The if statement checks if any entries are in the `statuslist.txt` then uses `dd` to wipe them.

```
sdx=$(lsscsi | awk '{if ($5 == "R001" && $5 != "-" ) print $NF}' | awk '{ print $0}')
x=$(cat /home/user/statuslist.txt | awk '{if ( $1 ~/slot#*/)print $1}')

if [ ${#wipe[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
        for i in $x; do dd if=/dev/zero of=$sdx bs=10M status=progress; done
        echo "Following hard drives are getting wiped:" $x
else
        echo "dd didn't work"
fi
```

My expectations for this script are, that it uses `dd` only on hard drives form the `statuslist.txt`. The purpose of this list is, to avoid re-wiping already wiped hard drives. The entries for wiped hard drives will be deleted form the text file.

The problem I have is the regex for this variable.
`x=$(cat /home/user/statuslist.txt | awk '{if ( $0 ~/slot#*/) print $1}')`

I don't get any output.

Comment: Shouldn’t you be looking for `Slot` (capital ‘S’)?

Comment: Hi @StephenKitt, you are right. I get now an output but only the first entry from the ```statuslist.txt.``` How do i get all of them?

Comment: Just curious: in the first line of your script a) what do you think `$5 == "R001" && $5 != "-"` is doing? b) what do you think `| awk '{ print $0}'`  is doing? Do you understand that it's your use of `echo $slist` without quotes that's causing all of the values from that variable to be compressed into a single line (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the fields:

```
x=$(awk '{ for (i = 1; i < NF; i++) { if ($i ~ /^Slot#/) { print $(i + 1) } } }' /home/user/statuslist.txt)
```

(this also fixes the “slot” typo, case is significant).

I’m not sure how you’re trying to use that in the subsequent loop, you’re not changing `sdx` as you change `x`...

Comment: thank you very much. The loop works great for my purpose. 
Sdx is a variable where it specifies the device name. I didn't know about awk loops before that is why I will try it to create a loop for sdx variable.
``` ```